# Deleted SQLLite notes records are once more retrieved after Restart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

EDIT: It appears this bug only takes place on "Restart" and do not take place on hot reload.

I'm facing the issue where the notes that got already deleted from SQLLite database come back after restart. I'm not sure it why does it happen, for example I delete one note then restart the app and the same note reappears on the screen. It's weird because previously I deleted the note using the same code and they didn't come back and they are gone forever.

Any ideas why does it happen? It seems as if the notes stays in the database after deletion and then once the DB is retrieved they come back but I checked and the await database.delete() is called every time.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notepad/screens/Note.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

//Singleton
class DatabaseProvider {
  static Database? _database;
  static bool _isDatabaseInitialized = false;

  static Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_isDatabaseInitialized) {
      return _database!;
    }
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    _isDatabaseInitialized = true;
    return _database!;
  }

  static Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    // Set the path to the database. Note: Using the `join` function from the
    // `path` package is best practice to ensure the path is correctly
    // constructed for each platform.
    final path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'notes.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      // When the database is first created, create a table to store notes.
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
        return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE Notes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, subtitle TEXT)',
        );
      },
      // Set the version. This executes the onCreate function and provides a
      // path to perform database upgrades and downgrades.
      version: 1,
    );
  }
}

class ListOfNotes extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListOfNotes({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListOfNotes> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<ListOfNotes> {
  bool _isInitialized = false;

  var noteTitle = [];
  var noteContent = [];

  late var originalNoteTitle = [];
  late var originalNoteContent = [];

  late var isSelected =
      List<bool>.filled(noteTitle.length, false, growable: true);
  late var tileColor =
      List<Color>.filled(noteTitle.length, Colors.white, growable: true);

  var appBarActionsEnabled = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: noteTitle.length,
          prototypeItem: ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            title:
                Text(noteTitle.firstWhere((element) => true, orElse: () => '')),
            subtitle: Text(
                noteContent.firstWhere((element) => true, orElse: () => '')),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
                title: Text(noteTitle[index]),
                subtitle: Text(noteContent[index]),
                onLongPress: () {
                  toggleSelection(index);
                  toggleActions();
                },
                onTap: () {
                  _editNote(context, index);
                },
                selected: isSelected[index],
                tileColor: tileColor[index],
                enabled: true);
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteSelectedNotes() async {
    final database = await DatabaseProvider.database;
    // Remove the Note from the database.
    for (int i = 0; i < noteTitle.length; i++) {
      if (isSelected[i] == true) {
        await database.delete(
          'Notes',
          // Use a `where` clause to delete a specific note.
          where: 'id = ?',
          // Pass the Note's id as a whereArg to prevent SQL injection.
          whereArgs: [i],
        );
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
        if (isSelected[i] == true) {
          noteTitle.removeAt(i);
          noteContent.removeAt(i);
          originalNoteTitle.removeAt(i);
          originalNoteContent.removeAt(i);
          isSelected.removeAt(i);
          tileColor.removeAt(i);
        }
      }
    });
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeNotes();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeNotes() async {
    if (!_isInitialized) {
      await _retrieveNotes();
      _isInitialized = true;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _retrieveNotes() async {
    var tempNoteTitleWait = [];
    var tempNoteContentWait = [];

    final database = await DatabaseProvider.database;

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await selectNotesDB(database);

    for (final row in result) {
      tempNoteTitleWait.add(row['title']);
      tempNoteContentWait.add(row['subtitle']);
    }

    setState(() {
      noteTitle = List<String>.from(tempNoteTitleWait);
      noteContent = List<String>.from(tempNoteContentWait);
      originalNoteTitle = List<String>.from(tempNoteTitleWait);
      originalNoteContent = List<String>.from(tempNoteContentWait);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there must be some diffrent indexing on the database and the Lists that I'm using, so as a half measure I used `title[index]` instead, and it appears to work. I'm not sure why it doesn't delete two notes with the same title while doing it this way, but it work as intended so I guess it would be an instance of Todd Howard "It just works".

```
Future<void> deleteSelectedNotes() async {
  final database = await DatabaseProvider.database;

  List<int> indicesToDelete = [];
  // Remove the Note from the database.
  for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
    if (isSelected[i] == true) {
      await database.delete(
        'Notes',
        // Use a `where` clause to delete a specific note.
        where: 'title = ?',
        // Pass the Note's id as a whereArg to prevent SQL injection
        whereArgs: [noteTitle[i]],
      );

      indicesToDelete.add(i);
    }
  }
```